# Getting error while using import { useState } from 'react';

Tags: reactjs

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

const root10 = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('Xy'));
const element10 = <Pile />; 
root10.render(element10);

 function Pile() {
  return (
    <img
      src="https://i.imgur.com/QIrZWGIs.jpg"
      alt="Alan L. Hart"
    />
  );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test Page-React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<link rel="icon" type="./x-icon" href="./favicon.ico">

<h3>https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/describing-the-ui</h3>
<h4>https://transform.tools/html-to-jsx</h4>  
<h5>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules</h5>


<div id="Xy"></div>

    <!-- Load  React. -->
    <!-- Note: if deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <!-- Load your React component. -->
 <script type="module" src="test.js"></script>

  
  </body>
</html>
```

I am learning from the official react guide...I entered the code  `import { useState } from 'react';` on top of my js file..and jsx preprocessing is sucess but rendering in chrome is giving me  console log as :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Note:chrome rendering without the `import { useState } from 'react';` works fine.

Babel version[image: error]n: 6.26.0 (babel-core 6.26.3) is installed as per react official install guide: npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3

Comment: Use React.useState(), without the import.

Comment: still error JSCode: React.useState()
const root10 = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('Xy'));
const element10 = <Pile />; 
root10.render(element10);

 function Pile() {
  return (
    <img
      src="https://i.imgur.com/QIrZWGIs.jpg"
      alt="Alan L. Hart"
    />
  );
}

Comment: I meant, if you need to use the "useState" hook, use it as "React.useState()".

If you're not using it in your code, remove it completely.

Comment: Please share how you are using the hook.

Comment: deliberately I am not using the hook right now as I wanted code to be rendered properly while using the React.useState(), or the import { useState } from 'react';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251598/discussion-between-michael36-and-anton-podolsky).

Comment: tl;dr

You need a build tool like Babel to produce a .js file for you which you can then run in the browser if you want to use the "import ..." syntax.
If you're writing plain javascript, you need to use the global variables exposed by the libraries you import via the <script> tag.

Comment: no errors after using npx babel --watch sr --out-dir . --presets react-app/prod
only chrome rendering html cause error attached in my initial question